# stack overflow with pandas_datareader

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I have python threads that are querying from a mongodb and this is the first time I've run into this error. It's also the first time I've queried my db this much. It's a large db with 500 million documents. Here is the error:

```
IV
BIVV
adding AAXN to retry list
adding AABA to retry list
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
```

I didn't code the adding comments. Python seems to be adding these stock symbols back on the queue moments before the stack overflow error and then all the threads die.

I tried calling gc.collect on each iteration of get from the queue but that didn't fix it. This happens with 15 threads and 5 threads, at the same stock symbols. I'm pretty sure I don't have any memory leaks. Should I just del all the variables each thread has at each iteration? Maybe try multiprocess instead of multithreading? Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

I looked more into the "adding" comment, and its being printed by pandas_datareader. Specifically mstar/daily.py.

It appears that retry count is never incremented. Which creates the recursive stack overflow error.

```
def _dl_mult_symbols(self, symbols):
    failed = []
    symbol_data = []
    for symbol in symbols:

        params = self._url_params()
        params.update({"ticker": symbol})

        try:
            resp = requests.get(self.url, params=params)
        except Exception:
            if symbol not in failed:
                if self.retry_count == 0:
                    warn("skipping symbol %s: number of retries "
                         "exceeded." % symbol)
                    pass
                else:
                    print("adding %s to retry list" % symbol)
                    failed.append(symbol)
        else:
            if resp.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
                jsondata = resp.json()
                if jsondata is None:
                    failed.append(symbol)
                    continue
                jsdata = self._restruct_json(symbol=symbol,
                                             jsondata=jsondata)
                symbol_data.extend(jsdata)
            else:
                raise Exception("Request Error!: %s : %s" % (
                    resp.status_code, resp.reason))

        time.sleep(self.pause)

    if len(failed) > 0 and self.retry_count > 0:
        # TODO: This appears to do nothing since
        # TODO: successful symbols are not added to
        self._dl_mult_symbols(symbols=failed)
        self.retry_count -= 1
    else:
        self.retry_count = 0

    if not symbol_data:
        raise ValueError('All symbols were invalid')
    elif self.retry_count == 0 and len(failed) > 0:
        warn("The following symbols were excluded do to http "
             "request errors: \n %s" % failed, SymbolWarning)

    symbols_df = DataFrame(data=symbol_data)
    dfx = symbols_df.set_index(["Symbol", "Date"])
    return dfx
```